# MYSQL Query for sum

Tags: mysql

I'm writing a php tool,
from my query I get below output

```
| dst        | count(*) |
| 0280302002 |       31 |
| 0280304115 |       83 |
| 0280304121 |       80 |
| 0280304124 |       10 |
| 0280304136 |        1 |
| 2002       |        3 |
| 4115       |       12 |
| 4121       |       10 |
| 4124       |        2 |
```

What I need is only 10 digits output.

Ex:- 31( value of 0280302002 + 3(value of  2002 ) = output should be
 0280302002 =34

Is there any way to get this value ?

my query

```
select dst,count(*) from cdr where calldate between '2019-01-01 00:00:00' and '2019-01-31 23:59:59' and dst in ('4121', '2006','2011''4124','0280304121', '0280302006','0280302011','0280304124') and length(src)>4 group by dst order by dst;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `case when` expression and `concat()` function

```
select case when length(dst)=4 then concat('028030',dst) else dst end as dst,count(*) 
from cdr 
where calldate between '2019-01-01 00:00:00' and '2019-01-31 23:59:59' and 
dst in ('4121', '2006','2011''4124','0280304121', '0280302006','0280302011','0280304124') and length(src)>4 
group by case when length(dst)=4 then concat('028030',dst) else dst end
order by dst
```

Answer (score 0):

You can treat `dst` as a string and take its four right-most characters:

```
SEECT    RIGHT(dst, 4), COUNT(*)
FROM     cdr
WHERE    calldate BETWEEN '2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-01-31 23:59:59' AND 
         dst IN ('4121', '2006','2011''4124','0280304121', '0280302006', '0280302011', '0280304124') AND
         LENGTH(src) > 4
GROUP BY RIGHT(dst,4)
ORDER BY 1;
```